# Unable to generate maven changelog on Jenkins

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to generate a maven changelog on Jenkins. It works fine on my local machine, at the same time it works well on remote machine where jenkins service is running.

But it does not works well on Jenkins

```
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.scm.manager.plexus.DefaultScmManager - Working directory: C:\h\workspace\b.fsa-data-extractor\data-extractor
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.ChangeLogMojo - Provider message:
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.ChangeLogMojo - The svn command failed.
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.ChangeLogMojo - Command output:
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.ChangeLogMojo - 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

I am not sure , why it is giving me svn error. Any inputs would be helpful ?

I am using 2.3 version of the plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <dates>
        <date>${previous.tag.date}</date>
      </dates>
      <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
      <type>date</type>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Your svn command is failling, might be either your password is changed or your svn configuration is not proper for jenkins... go to terminal and check if its working on command line for jenkins codebase.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have installed SVN on command line on the build server ` 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`...

Comment: svn is installed on the Jenkins server. I have checked it using 'svn --version'